# Controlling DC motor with Arduino Mega and Simple-H HV Motor Shield

Tags: c++, c, arduino, motordriver

I am trying to control a single DC motor using a Simple-H HV Motor Shield and a H-bridge connection. I need to control both speed and direction using the serial monitor (for example "f 220" would mean forward at a speed of 220). Here is the code I have:

M1 causes the motor to go forward, and M2 causes the motor to go backward.

Here is the error: no matching function for call to 'HardwareSerial::print()'

I don't know if this is even the correct way of coding this. I would just like some help with programming this as I'm pretty new at Arduino coding.

```
const int PWM1 = 2;  //PA - PWM A (M1)
const int PWM2 = 3;  //PB - PWM B (M2)
const int MotorEnable = 4;  //EA - Enable A
const int TestLED = 13;  //LED that tests whether going forward or back. LED lights up = forward, //non-lit = reverse

void setup() {
  pinMode(PWM1, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(PWM2, OUTPUT);

  Serial.begin(9600);
}
void loop() {

   int VariableMove = Serial.print(); // *** ERROR is here! ***
   int speed = Serial.parseInt();

  if (Serial.available() > 0) {
      if (VariableMove = "f" && speed >= 0 && speed <= 255) {
        digitalWrite(MotorEnable, HIGH);
        digitalWrite(PWM1, HIGH);
        digitalWrite(PWM2, LOW);
        Serial.println("Going Forward");
        analogWrite(PWM1, speed);
        }
     if (VariableMove = "r" && speed >= 0 && speed <= 255)  {
        digitalWrite(MotorEnable, HIGH); 
        digitalWrite(PWM1, LOW);
        digitalWrite(PWM2, HIGH); 
        Serial.println("Coming Back");
        analogWrite(PWM2, speed);
       }
       }
  }
```

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: [**How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: I tried setting a variable for the input from the Serial monitor. I was trying to store what is said in the monitor so that the motor will keep running until another command is given.

Comment: _'Here is the error: no matching function for call to `HardwareSerial::print()`'_ The code you show doesn't relate in any way to this error message (unless you show what's `Serial`, and where you're calling `HardwareSerial::print()` actually)!

Comment: The error comes up for this line:  int VariableMove = Serial.print();

Comment: Sure it returns an `int`?? Doesn't make much sense for me! What are you actually trying to do?

Comment: The user would input a character (f or r) to control direction and along with it would input a int (between 0 and 255) to control speed. An example would be "f 255". I was trying to store these so that the motor would keep running until another command is given. So I tried creating two variables.

Comment: How does `Serial.print();` trigger input of a character?!? What do you want to achieve there? Does the class `HardwareSerial` provide this function? What does the documentation say about it? Please clarify all of these questions, before asking here!

Comment: I'm sorry but it looks like there's a misunderstanding. The way I learned Serial.print is like this: if(Serial.print("r")) then do something. This means that when a user enters "r" in the serial monitor, something that was specified in the code would happen. Here I am trying to create a variable that stores what is entered in the serial monitor. Am I going about this the wrong way then? What is the correct way?

Comment: _'The way I learned Serial.print is like this ...'_ I'd doubt this is correct, can you provide a reference link that confirms your understanding? Anyways the compiler says **NO**. (Also note the function takes a string parameter!)

Comment: Then tell me what the correct way is. How would I be able to make the motor go both the direction and speed the user inputs into the Serial monitor?

Comment: Making your code compile is a 1st step forward (pun intended) ...

Comment: I am asking as to what I need to do, as in code needed, to make this compile - to make this correct.

Comment: The question is, what do you intend `int VariableMove = Serial.print();` to do?? It neither compiles, nor your interpretation what it does seems to be right. Did you mean another `Serial.println("Get direction"); char VariableMove = Serial.parseChar();` (or something similar)

Comment: Ignoring that line - you've clearly made your point that it is incorrect. What I want is for the user to be able to type in a letter that controls direction and a number for speed in the same line of Serial Monitor (an example being "f 220"). How would I do this? Forget my incorrect code.

Comment: I mentioned some way with my last comment, just refer to the documentation of the `HardwareSerial` class, I don't know if there's actually a function `parseChar()`, but there will certainly be a method to read a single character from input. Also note you'll need to compare with `'r'` and `'f'`, not `"r"` and `"f"`!

Answer (score 4):

The line you say is throwing the error:

```
 int VariableMove = Serial.print(); // *** ERROR is here! ***
```

It is unclear what you are expecting that line to do but there are two things wrong with it:

1. `Serial.print()` requires an argument: the data to be printed. The error results from calling that method without an argument since, as the error message states: `no matching function for call to 'HardwareSerial::print()'`
2. Less a coding error than a usage error: [Serial.print()](http://arduino.cc/en/Serial/Print) returns a `long` representing the number of bytes written yet later in the code you are testing if it is String "f" etc. So you probably want `Serial.read()` or one of the other methods for reading incoming data.

Finally this line  `if (VariableMove = "f"`

A single `=` is **assignment** To test **equivalence** you use two `==` as in:

`if (VariableMove == "f"` That's a common error to make.

from the Serial lib documentation:

> Returns
>
> size_t (long): print() returns the number of bytes written, though
>   reading that number is optional

Comment: `VariableMove == "f"` This is also blatantly wrong, should most probably `VariableMove == 'f'` as soon the OP fixed his code to read a single character from user input.

Answer (score -2):

Updated below.

`Serial.print()` is a function that "returns the number of bytes written", but you have no input to that function and therefore there is a compile-time error.

```
const int rightCW = 6, leftCW = 11, rightCCW = 5, leftCCW = 10;

void setup()
{
  Serial.begin(9600);
  initMotors();

}

void loop()
{
  delay(10);
  analogWrite(rightCW,255);     
}

void initMotors()
{
  //initialize motors
  pinMode(rightCW, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(leftCW, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(rightCCW, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(leftCCW, OUTPUT);
}
```

Assuming you have correctly wired the motors, you can edit right, left CW and CCW's (clockwise and counterclockwise) pins to whatever your control pins are. This program will simply test whether or not you can get one motor working.

Take this for the H-bridge diagram, in case: http://9m.no/쵉쀨
Corners go to the power rail, inner two on each side go to ground, 1A, 2A go to control pins on Arduino, 1Y, 2Y go to motor's two wires. The same applies for any other motor you might have.

**UPDATE (see comments below):**

You will want something like

```
String input = "";
String result = "";
while (Serial.available() > 0)
{
  char temp = Serial.read();
  if (temp == '\n')
  {
    result = input;
    input = "";
    break; 
  }
  else
  {
    input += temp; 
  }
}
```

Serial.read() is the function that reads in one byte at a time.

Comment: Besides your introductory sentence, what does all this stuff has to do with the error mentioned in the question??

Comment: Oh. I was under the impression that you wanted general help with motors. I pointed out the error in the line that you asked for, and suggested an alternative program that you could adapt to your needs, and take input such as "f 220" or something.

Comment: Sorry, might want to stick all the analogWrite stuff in void loop().

Comment: Thank you for answering, but I don't believe that this is what I need. My motor does work - I've tested that before. What I need is how to make the motor go in the direction and speed the user inputs into the Serial Monitor

Comment: I think I may have fixed your issue. To elaborate further, the last snippet of code will take inputs of letters and add them to a string until you press the enter, or "return" character. Then it will store the current amassed characters in a new variable and reset the old one (might be a little redundant, but I think it works). Personally, I think you might want to take the forward/backward input and the power input on different lines for simplicity, as your parseInt() function doesn't really work if there are non integer characters in the string.